# Render Partial within a Partial MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

I have 2 partial views and each of them has a different View Model associated to it. 
First Partial View Called "AccountNamesPartial":

```
@using GACharts.Models.IntergratedAccount;
@model UpdateAccount
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Accounts.Count(); i++)
{
<li>
    <label>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Accounts[i].Id)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Accounts[i].Selected)
        @Model.Accounts[i].Name
    </label>
</li>
}
```

So the partial view above is what I want to @Html.RenderPartial("AccountNamesPartial") in my Second Partial View:

```
@model GACharts.Models.ReportViewModel
<select class="form-control" id="ChartViewId" name="ChartViewId">
                        <option>Select View</option>
@{Html.RenderPartial("AccountNamesPartial", new GACharts.Models.IntergratedAccount.UpdateAccount());}
</select>
```

I am no longer getting stack trace errors, but the data wont appear on the 2nd partial view. Any ideas/suggestions to get it working?

Comment: It looks like you're initializing a new instance of `UpdateAccount` and passing it to the partial view. Since it's a new instance it wouldn't have any data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a form to do an update necessarily is going to require you fetch the actual object you're updating to get it's data. If you want to continue using partials, that means you're going to need to have that `UpdateAccount` view model already present on your `ReportViewModel`:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    ...

    public UpdateAccount UpdateAccount { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you'd populate that in your action before returning your view:

```
var account = // fetch, from DB, for example
reportModel.UpdateAccount = new UpdateAccount { /* map properties over here */ };
```

Then, in your partial:

```
@Html.Partial("AccountNamesPartial", Model.UpdateAccount)
```

Alternatively, you could use a child action:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult AccountNames()
{
    var account = // fetch, from DB, for example
    var model = new UpdateAccount { /* map properties */ };
    return PartialView("AccountNamesPartial", model);
}
```

Then, in your partial:

```
@Html.Action("AccountNames")
```